# How to remove a tag from newer commits in git?

Tags: git, github

I created a new tag `v1.0.0` and git tagged commits `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` with `v1.0.0`. `a, b, c, d` are the commit ids:

```
d -> Newest
c
b
a -> Oldest
```

Here is an example repository: https://github.com/axelthat/git-test. See how each commits are tagged with v1.0.0.
[image]

But I want to tag only the commits `a` and `b` with `v1.0.0`. How do I do this?

Comment: `a, b, c, d` are the commit ids. I gave it as an example.

Comment: @Axel You didn't understand AD7six's question. We'd need to know what you mean by that, since it is nonsensical in git. Why do you *think* all these commits are tagged with your tag?

Comment: Well I made 4 commits: `a, b, c and d`. Afterwards, I ran `git tag v1.0.0` and it tagged all those commits to `v1.0.0`.

Comment: @Axel No, it's likely your interface which is tricking you. Tags point to *one* commit only, by design.

Comment: @Axel `A tag is a pointer to one commit`. Just delete elder tag point to d, and create a new tag point to b.

Comment: Okay here is an example: https://github.com/axelthat/git-test. Check each commits in the github website. They are tagged with `v1.0.0`.

Comment: @shanfeng How do I delete a tag point to d?

Comment: @Axel That's what I suspected, github's interface makes it unclear. For each commit it shows the closest commit in the ancestry if no tag points directly at it, so it leads you to *think* all these commits point to the same. But they don't. Take a look at [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe), *this* is what is shown for commits on your github view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A git tag points at *one* commit

> See how each commits are tagged with v1.0.0.

This phrase from the question is a misunderstanding or misrepresentation of the information github is displaying.

The commits `a`, `b` and `c` are *part of* tag `1.0.0` they are not "tagged with" `1.0.0` - this difference in terminology may seem pedantic, but is the root of the confusion in the question and comments (which can now all be deleted), a tag can only point at one commit.

An example to reinforce that, consider the following repo:

```
➜  git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/so/.git/
➜  echo "a" > README.md
➜  git add README.md
➜  git commit -m "a"
[main (root-commit) 3900dc2] a
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README.md
➜  echo "b" > README.md
➜  git commit -am "b"
[main e5dbd9c] b
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
➜  echo "c" > README.md
➜  git commit -am "c"
[main 79d52b2] c
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
➜  echo "d" > README.md
➜  git commit -am "d"
[main 5d6e012] d
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
➜
```

This has created a git repo with commits. If I now create a tag and look at the history:

```
➜  git tag v1.0.0
➜  git log --graph --decorate --oneline
* 5d6e012 (HEAD -> main, tag: v1.0.0) d
* 79d52b2 c
* e5dbd9c b
* 3900dc2 a
```

There are 4 commits and *one* of them (`d`) is also the tag 1.0.0 - the other commits are the ancestors of `d`, and the tag.

A tag is actually just a file - it's freely available to take a look at:

```
➜  cat .git/refs/tags/v1.0.0
5d6e012b898e87617a9e1d138cd072fa96053009
```

### How to tag not-head?

> I want to tag only the commits a and b with v1.0.0. How do I do this?

Rephrasing to match git terminology this is: "How to create tag `v1.0.0` for commit `b`?"

Which is pretty easy to do, all of this can be done via [github's ui](https://github.com/axelthat/git-test/tags) but I'll demonstrate here the cli steps:

1. Delete the incorrect tag locally

```
➜  git tag -d v1.0.0
```

2. Delete the incorrect tag on the remote

```
➜  git push --delete origin v1.0.0
```

3. Create the correct tag locally

```
➜  git tag v1.0.0 e5dbd9c # the sha for commit "b"
```

Note the local state is now:

```
➜  git log --graph --decorate --oneline
* 5d6e012 (HEAD -> main) d
* 79d52b2 c
* e5dbd9c (tag: v1.0.0) b
* 3900dc2 a
```

4. update remote with tags

```
➜  git push --tags
```

And done :).